# Does a VTBL contains pointers to non-virtual functions?

Tags: c++

I'm having hard time to understand why the code below print C::f2 instead of B::f2.

[From Charles Bailey answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12661309/806963)

> When a non-virtual function is called the implementation must use the
>   static type of the object on which the function is being called to
>   determine the correct function to call. A function stored in a vtable
>   accessed by a vptr will be dependent on the dynamic type of the
>   object, not any static type of a reference or pointer through which it
>   is being accessed.

I'm a bit lost, Inside A::f1 there is a call to f2. How does the compiler know which method to call?

My assemption:

1. The compiler somehow remmber that we are inside object of type C.
2. The compiler check if C contain a non virtual method name f2.
   a. if yes, run it.
   b. use the object's pointer to access his vtbl and run the right f2.

Am I right?

```
struct A
{
    void f1()
    {
        f2();
    }
    virtual void f2()
    {
        cout<<"A::f2"<<endl;
    }
};
struct B:public A
{
    virtual void f2()
    {
        cout<<"B::f2"<<endl;
    }
};
struct C:public B
{
    void f2()
    {
        cout<<"C::f2"<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    C c1;
    c1.f1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may get answer from this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: short answer: no, because it's the virtual table and they're not virtual.

Comment: When you override a virtual function, writing `virtual` in the derived class is optional. So `C::f2` is a virtual function that overrides `A::f2` and `B::f2` whether you write `virtual` in  `C` or not.

Comment: @interjay can you specify a source for what you are saying?

Comment: No, but it should be in every basic C++ book.

Comment: found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404797/in-c-is-a-function-automatically-virtual-if-it-overrides-a-virtual-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every member function has an implicit `this` parameter. The static type of `this` inside `f1` is always `A * const`. This is true for any member function. The static type of the implicit object parameter is the enclosing class where the function is **defined**.

The call inside `f1` is resolved as `this->f2()`. Since this is a call via pointer, the function `f2` is dispatched dynamically. This is despite the fact the `f1` is not virtual, and will always be called by static dispatch.

By whatever mechanism the compiler uses (a VTable is an *implementation detail*, not mandated by the C++ standard itself), we get a call to `C::f2`.

So your assumptions need some revision, I'd say.

---

To answer your question as you specified in the comments. `C::f2` is virtual. You may have omitted the virtual specifier when overriding it, but there is no "unvirtualising" it.

Comment: Without specifing @interjay comment, I don't understand how you conclude that `C::f2` will be called. If you are agree please right that down, it will be very helpful to understand.  If you disagree, please explain more how you conclude that `C::f2` will be called. Thanks.

Comment: @StavAlfi - I do believe you completely skipped the second paragraph. A call **via pointer**. If the called member is a virtual function, it will be called dynamically.

Comment: Okay, but C::f2 is not defined as virtual so C::f2 is not registered in C VTBL so calling f2 dynamically should call to B::f2.

Comment: @StavAlfi - This is where your understanding suffers. Once a function is defined as virtual *once*, it's virtual in every derived class. Even if the virtual specifier isn't repeated.

Comment: And that is complelty answering my question :) I recommend you to add https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404843/806963 it to your answer. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @StavAlfi - Yeah, I see now what the question was really about.